# How to fix text rendering in fixed block?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Have problem with rendering text in Chrome browser, bug work if body have scroll (99% sites usually have, my too). I change only position, but text not work properly, how to fix that?

```js
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  $('.block').toggleClass('fixed');
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 5000px;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.block {
  position: static;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: red;
  background-color: #03121b;
}

.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block fixed">
  <h1>Some text blurred</h1>
</div>

<button id="button">toggle .block{ position: fixed; }</button>
```

Comment: maybe add `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` to the element so it behave the same whataver the position

Comment: @TemaniAfif, ty for help, this method fix the problem, but I still don`t know why that happens in chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Add this property to .block child element will fix this bug.